# Creating screen for android applications with Photoshop

Tags: android, layout, photoshop

I'm working on an android application and I was wondering if there is a way to create the different screen of my application in Photoshop and then using them in the in eclipse as the screens?

Comment: it is not possible.You can create graphics and use them in your xml files.

Comment: Photoshop CAN have a use, for any background of a view, say a button, or the background of your whole activity you can design the graphic in photoshop at different resolutions and set them in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In contrary to iOS, Android runs on a huge variety of devices with screen sizes and resolutions from tiny wrist-watches to full blown HD screens. Thus, it's not possible to create a complete screen with Photoshop and use it in your app.

Better have a look on the various Layouts and how to build them via XML layout files. Also you should have an idea of how nine-patch images work.